# What is responsible for calling and running a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

What is the component of docker that is responsible for actually calling and processing a `Dockerfile`?

I'm currently trying to install a product (Discourse) that is only released via a [docker image](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker). I'd like to make some changes to that image when the Discourse [launcher](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker/blob/87fd7172af8f2848d5118fdebada646c5996821b/launcher) script that wraps `docker` commands does a `docker pull` of the image.

I made the necessary changes to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker/blob/c87937dc40abe2791a128b4463a6a5ceba181be4/image/base/Dockerfile), but they don't appear to be being executed.

How do I get `docker pull` to actually use my changes to the `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker build` is the component of docker that actually runs the `Dockerfile`.

`docker pull` and `docker push` do not run the `Dockerfile`; they only download and upload pre-built image files from a docker registry, such as [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com). The images on the registry were generated using the `Dockerfile` at the `docker build` step (which was run by the developers of the product prior to it being `docker push`ed).

If you want to modify a release of a product's docker image, then `docker pull` is not what you need. You need to find their sources with the `Dockerfile` and download *that*, then `cd` into the directory where the `Dockerfile` lives, make your changes to it, and then execute:

```
docker build --tag 'my_local_image' .
```

The above command will build a new image tagged with the name `my_local_image` which you can use instead of the image that's `docker pull`ed from the Internet.

This macro view of how `Dockerfile`s are actually executed does not appear to be explained anywhere in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/), and if you're totally new to docker then it may be logical to falsely reason that a `Dockerfile` is run at the time that the `docker pull` command is run.